# scala reflection, cast type with asInstanceOf

Tags: scala, reflection, types, casting

I have

```
trait T
class C extends T
```

compiled to .class files. Run scala with `-cp <...>` to have type `T` available. Then load class C using reflection:

```
val loader = ScalaClassLoader fromURLs (/* List[URL] */)
val anyC = loader.tryToInitializeClass("C") getOrElse (/* throw something */)
val classC = anyC.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
```

How can I cast a `classC.newInstance` into type `T` like

```
val objC = classC.newInstance.asInstanceOf[T] 
// yields java.lang.ClassCastException: C cannot be cast to T
```

Answer (score 4):

You must be loading class `C` from a different classloader than the one `T` is being loaded from.

You've put both `T` and `C` on the REPLs classpath, so one option would be to load `C` via the system classloader. Sample REPL session,

```
scala> val loader = scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader.getSystemLoader
loader: scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader =
  scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anon$1@985d2e0

scala> val anyC = loader.tryToInitializeClass("C") getOrElse (sys.error("Boom"))
anyC: Class[Nothing] = class C

scala> val classC = anyC.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]
classC: Class[T] = class C
```

Nb. this isn't really a Scala-specific question any longer.

Comment: So, is there any way to "merge" those two classloaders?

Comment: It really depends what you're trying to do. I've edited the answer to show one option.

Comment: Yeah, I want to check whether the user implemented the `trait` provided. I found the way
    `val loader = ScalaClassLoader fromURLs (/* List[URL] */, classOf[T].getClassLoader)`

That's all. Thank for your help!